# Eliminating an if statement that only needs to happen once

Tags: python, if-statement, file-io, coding-efficiency

I'm parsing a file and am using `if` statements to "find" sections in the file. The logic done in the `if` statement takes in the data from that section holds and parses it. At the end of each `if` statement the current line is set to the end of that section. These files are around 200,000 lines and the script is processing x number of files at a time; I'm trying to keep efficiency in mind.

Here's a code sample:

```
section = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if section[0]:
            parseFileSection()
            line = current_line
        if section[1]:
            parseFileSection()
            line = current_line
        if section[2]:
            parseFileSection()
            line = current_line
```

Here's an example of a file:

```
Section 1
data
.
.
Section 2
.
.
Section 2
.
.
Section 2
.
.
Section 3
.
.
Section 2
.
.
```

Is there a way to not check the if statements for `Section 1` and `Section 3` since they only appear once in the data?

One thought is to somehow loop through the `section` array and pop that value off when it's "used". But this will involve a lot of repeated checking as well. In addition to that, some sections are not parsed the same way, so it's not as simple as checking the section, calling a parse function, and popping off that section.

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve here. *if section[0]* will always be True. It would help if you provided sample input and desired output

Comment: Use a loop? `for _ in section: parseFileSection()` ?

Comment: If you want to parse text that mathces a certain form in your document, I recommend you use regex (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). You can use re.findall() function to get all the matches, if you process the parsed data afterwards, you should have an array eg. "processed_sections" where you append a section once it's processed and then check if the current section is not in processed_sections

Comment: Add the most common ifs at the top and at the end of each if section add the continue command.

Comment: This code sample does a poor job of illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the extra if statement(s) are negligible unless you have a lot of them and/or you have several orders of magnitude more data (I used to process 100s of Gb files in python so I have a little exp with this)

That said, no harm in removing the sections.
I assume you have some typos in your sudo code -- I expect you mean something like this:

```
section = ["section1", "section2", "section3"]

current_section = ''

def parseFileSectionType(line):
  for s in section:
    if s in line:
      current_section = s
      return s
  if current_section:
    return current_section
  return "unknown"

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        section = parseFileSectionType(line) # <-- assuming you have some function that determines which section you're in
        if section == section[0]:
            parsed_line = parseFileSection1(line) # <-- parseFileSection1 is the function responsible for parsing section1
        if section == section[1]:
            parsed_line = parseFileSection2(line) # <-- parseFileSection2 is the function responsible for parsing section2
        if section == section[2]:
            parsed_line = parseFileSection3(line) # <-- parseFileSection3 is the function responsible for parsing section3
```

In which case I'd do this instead:

```
section_mapper = {
  "section1": parseFileSection1, # <-- parseFileSection1 is the function responsible for parsing section1
  "section2": parseFileSection2, # <-- parseFileSection2 is the function responsible for parsing section2
  "section3": parseFileSection3, # <-- parseFileSection3 is the function responsible for parsing section3
}

def parseFileSectionType(line):
  for s in section_mapper.keys():
    if s in line:
      current_section = s
      return s
  if current_section:
    return current_section
  return "unknown"

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # parsed_line = section_mapper[parseFileSectionType(line)](line) # Split into two lines for readability
        section = parseFileSectionType(line) # <-- assuming you have some function that determines which section you're in
        parsed_line = section_mapper[section](line) # processes the line with the appropriate function from the section_mapper
```

Comment: This doesn't quite fit my use case, each section has a different format so I can't parse them the same way. This is why I'm using multiple if statements.

Comment: The pattern suggested by @Schalton is a good one. For your particular case, you should build a list of lines between the sections and pass that to the function that is responsible for that particular section format. I would also add that you should probably think about multi-processing (one process per file) given the apparent magnitude of your use-case

Comment: @LukeDev, the example I provided does apply a different parser to each section (the functions in the `section_mapper` dict, it just uses the `parseFileSectionType` to try to determine what section the line is -- hope that helps

Comment: LukeDev, if you want to update your question so that we can better understand what you're trying to accomplish we can be more helpful -- it isn't clear how your determining what section you're in as BrutusForcus mentioned